# Using Cloudflare with vBulletin 5.7.2

Tags: cloudflare, vbulletin

I'm installing vBulletin v5.7.2. PHP version is 7.4.2

Our website is https://www.example.com and the vBulletin forums are installed at https://www.example.com/forums/ . We enable Cloudflare Pro for the whole domain example.com, so the forums subdirectory is also affected.

Before starting installation, I pause Cloudflare on our site. The installation process is OK. And then I enable Cloudflare and then I login the Admin CP.

Then I notice that from time to time, the Admin CP will ask me to login repeatedly, or some frames requires to login, like below:

[image]

If I pause Cloudflare on our site, then wait for about 10 mins, then everything will be OK again.

I search online and find this post https://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=324748 and this one https://forum.vbulletin.com/forum/vb...udflare-issues , both said it is necessary to set a Cloudflare page rule to solve the issue.

So I setup a page rule as below, trying to disable everything possible:

[image]

But that still not working.

I have added the following lines to config.php:

```
$config['Misc']['proxyiplist'] = 'all';
$config['Misc']['proxyipheader'] = 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP';​
```

But still not working.